# git rebase --continue and --stepback?

Tags: git

Is there a way to step back a commit during an interactive rebase?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Yes there is. How to step back during an interactive rebase:

1. Get the commit hash of your current HEAD, for example with `git rev-parse HEAD`
2. run `git rebase --edit-todo`
3. insert a pick with that hash to the top of that file `pick <hash from step 1>`
4. run `git reset --hard HEAD^` (this is a hard reset so if you have done anything you want to keep make sure to store it somewhere e.g. `git stash` before you run the command)

Now you are still in the rebase but one commit back and you are free to continue rebasing with

5. `git rebase --continue`.

If you don't want the undone commit to be picked straight up without edits you can add `edit <HASH>` instead of `pick <HASH>` to the todo list (*step 3*).

Idea from: [http://arigrant.com/blog/2014/5/4/git-rebase-stepping-forward-and-back](http://web.archive.org/web/20161214103546/http://arigrant.com/blog/2014/5/4/git-rebase-stepping-forward-and-back)

Addendum 3: If you are worried of missing a hash in the rebase, you can compare your todo file (`.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo`) with the original one (`.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo.backup`) as per comment from @Andrew Keeton .

Addendum 1 and 2: You can remember more hashes, reset to an even earlier point and add multiple picks to redo more than one commit. When you edit the todo list it also contains a large comment about the different commands available:

```
pick 8f8b9645c1c python: remove declare_namespace

# Rebase 803c25a8314..8f8b9645c1c onto 803c25a8314 (1 command)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup [-C | -c] <commit> = like "squash" but keep only the previous
#                    commit's log message, unless -C is used, in which case
#                    keep only this commit's message; -c is same as -C but
#                    opens the editor
# x, exec <command> = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# b, break = stop here (continue rebase later with 'git rebase --continue')
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
# l, label <label> = label current HEAD with a name
# t, reset <label> = reset HEAD to a label
# m, merge [-C <commit> | -c <commit>] <label> [# <oneline>]
# .       create a merge commit using the original merge commit's
# .       message (or the oneline, if no original merge commit was
# .       specified); use -c <commit> to reword the commit message
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
```

Comment: @JohannesMüller The question specifically asks about step back in an interactive rebase.

Comment: Note that when you do this during interactive rebase and git stops because of a merge conflict, you'll also need to manually add the commit that's about the be applied. This is not included anymore in the TODO list. So if you don't include that manually you'll loose that commit in the new history. I couldn't figure out how to ask git for this hash yet, but my GUI client shows it to me so that's what worked for me.

Comment: I think your answer suggests the right idea, but the answer itself could be improved. The idea is: look at what's in the git log, and add all of the commits as far back as you want to re-wind to the rebase todo, and then reset to the commit before the ones added to the list. It may be presumptuous to suggest the user should just pick the HEAD commit. Besides wouldn't pick just get you right back to where you are? You'd need edit or some other rebase command than pick on the one you're rolling back to.

Comment: @johnb003 I updated the answer a little bit. Your wording might still be better.

Comment: @RolfW. I found what seems to be the original rebase TODO list: *.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo.backup*.

Comment: To reiterate Rolf W.'s point, when you do the `git rebase --edit-todo`, it is **CRITICAL** to include the _current_ commit if a merge conflict has occurred, because it has **NOT** been committed to HEAD yet, but it's no longer in the todo list either.  You can get the short SHA-1 of this commit with `git rev-parse --short REBASE_HEAD` and add it to the start of the todo list with `pick <commit>`, or you can get the exact line from your original todo list with `tail -1 \`git rev-parse --show-toplevel\`/.git/rebase-merge/done`.  After this, `git reset --hard HEAD` will rewind the merge conflict.

Comment: Step 4 erased all my unstaged changes! The reason I needed to step back was because I was in an `edit` rebase step, forgot to stage, --amended, and --continued.

Comment: @AndrewKeeton Thanks, I put the info about the backup file in the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Actually you can even if you're not doing interactive rebase.

As johnb003 mentioned in his comment, when rebasing, you're really making a series of new commits. By doing something such as `git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit`, you can easily see all the commits you've already made through the rebase. Simply copy their hashes for easy reference later.

Then `git rebase --abort`, `git rebase -i <base_branch>`, copy the hashes you want to preserve, possibly change them to `edit` if you want to modify any of them, and continue

Answer (score 3):

Nope, as Magnus said.

However,

- git-rerere could come close to what you want in a way: if there were previous manual conflict resolutions that you didn't want to loose, you can enable `rerere` (prerecorded conflict resolutions) so that they will automatically be resolved in the same way on subsequent merges. Note that this means that you'll have to remember what part you want to resolve differently next time (presumably the goal of having a step-back in the first place?) because - well, rerere assumes you want to applies the same resolution again.

If you look at the implementation of rebase, you might be able to figure out alternative settings for GIT_WORK_TREE/GIT_DIR/GIT_INDEX; You could then perhaps use plumbing commands with a reflog for the rebase-in-progress `branch`?

- this takes you deep into undocumented internals (beyond the plumbing)
- you might just as well propose a patch to rebase that implements `--step-back`

Comment: I think this answer is wrong. Look at my "yes"-answer on how to step back.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can --continue to continue rebasing (e.g. after you have solved some conflict), --abort (undo and whole rebase process) or --skip to skip current patch.